# jQuery fadeIn doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, fadein

I'm using fadeIn to fade in my BG DIV's.

example:  http://commonmovement.com/MIP/about-mip.html

This works in all browsers except IE, where it just "pops" on.
Not sure how to fix this.

I tried using:

`$('#main.about_main').css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=0)');`
  `$('#main.about_main').fadeIn(2000);`

but no luck.

CSS:

`#main { height:100%; width:100%; padding:0; }`

`#main.about_main {display: none;}`

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
$('#main').hide().fadeIn(2000);
```

Comment: I wouldn't even put the `.about_main` qualifier there but otherwise +1, this is how I'd do it (assuming you didn't do CSS `display: none` for `#main`).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#main.about_main').css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=0)');
```

The DIV is transparent. Then how can it be seen?

Comment: I saw this on another post about the same issue and thought it was worth a try.

Comment: `filter` is IE specific. This line of CSS set the `div` to transparent, so no matter it's `display` is `none` or `block`, it won't be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Is that first line with the filter necessary? Have you tried it without? The display:none in the style sheet should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is not with IE, it's performance.

In my IE 8 worked just fine, but a pretty slow and ugly transition. On Chrome was pretty fluid

As you go to IE 7 or even 6 the performance should slower, because big DIV animation demands more from the browser.

Can you test this under IE 9? Or even on IE 8 on a machine with better CPU + RAM?

Comment: It works great on a higher end machine. I think the img file sizes are an issue